# Syntax for declaring variable and executing procedure in Aqua Data Studio?

Tags: oracle

If I run this in Oracle SQL Developer:

```
DECLARE
num NUMBER;
BEGIN
num :=5;
dbms_output.put_line(num);
END;
```

It returns "5"

If I run the same code in Aqua Data Studio 10.0.7 (with ';' statement separator checked):

> [Error] Script lines: 39-40 ------------------------
>    ORA-06550: line 2, column 7:
>   PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
>
> - & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between
>     || multiset member submultiset  Script line 38, statement line 2,
>     column 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have enabled one of the options ...

File->Option->General->[';' Statement Separator]
File->Option->Scripts->Oracle->[';' Statement Separator]

You need to disable them to run stored procedures.  "/" is a better statement separator used with Oracle.

Comment: Great.. Let me know if you need help with any other issues.